# Is the set of countable limit ordinals countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

It is probably a trivial question, but I have no clue about the answer. I know that the elements of $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, are the countable ordinals, of which there are uncountably many, but I am not sure if that applies to the number of limit ordinals before $\omega_1$ too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No: the set of countable limit ordinals has the same cardinality as the set of countable ordinals, i.e., $\omega_1$ (or $\aleph_1$, for those who prefer the aleph notation). Let $\Lambda$ be the set of non-successor countable ordinals (i.e., the countable limit ordinals together with $0$); then the map

$$\omega_1\to\Lambda:\alpha\mapsto\omega\cdot\alpha$$

is a bijection, where $\cdot$ is ordinal multiplication.

Comment: @scott but you can "define" a successor function for them right? I mean, there is no doubt about which is the next limit ordinal of a given countable limit ordinal (although this seems contradictory if they are uncountable, I am confused)

Comment: @julian: The bijection that I gave actually gives you the successor limit ordinal: the successor to $\omega\cdot\alpha$ is $\omega\cdot(\alpha+1)=\omega\cdot\alpha+\omega$. In general, if $\eta$ is any limit ordinal, countable or not, then $\eta+\omega$ (ordinal addition) is the next larger limit ordinal.

Comment: @scott I've always thought that a property of uncountable sets is that you cannot put their elements one after another. For instance, you can order the real numbers but you cannot tell which one is next to it. Isn't that what makes them uncountable? (nondenumerable). If you can define which one is next, why can't you pair them with the natural numbers?. Sorry if I am asking beyond the original question. I can put a new one

Comment: @julian: You’re confusing two rather different concepts. Look at the rational numbers: in their usual order no rational number has an immediate successor. However, there is a bijection $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$, and we can use that to define a **different** order on $\Bbb Q$ in which each rational does have an immediate successor. Assuming the axiom of choice, there is also a bijection $f$ from some well-ordered cardinal number $\kappa$ to $\Bbb R$, and we can use it to define a different order on $\Bbb R$ in which every element has a successor: the successor of $f(\xi)$ is $f(\xi+1)$. This isn’t ...

Comment: ... a matter of cardinality, but rather of whether we can well-order a set.

Comment: @julian: Uncountability simply means we can't inject into the natural numbers. There *do* exist uncountable well-ordered sets, though--such as $\omega_1$--and in a well-ordered set, you can always tell which one (if any) is "next" after a given element. The real numbers aren't well-ordered in the standard order, but even if they could be well-ordered, uncountability means that they still can't be matched one-to-one with the naturals.

Comment: I have a lot of misconceptions for what I can see! Thanks guys. But still, I cannot intuitively imagine how you can order a set into a "string" (I mean with one element following the next) and still not be able to put the naturals in order next to them (I also wrongly thought that a well-ordered set only required to be able to decide, given any two elements, which comes first, but didn't know it required a successor to be well defined)

Comment: @julian: Being able to say which of two elements comes first just means that you have a *linear* (also called *total*) order; a well-order is a linear order in which each non-empty set has a first element. (Thus, $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered in its usual order, but $\Bbb Z$ is not.) If $\langle X,\le\rangle$ is some well-order, $x\in X$, and $S(x)=\{y\in X:x<y\}\ne\varnothing$, then $S(x)$ has a first element, and that element must be the successor of $x$. // It’s not hard to visualize a well-ordered set that isn’t ordered like $\Bbb N$, though this particular example can be rearranged to look ...

Comment: ... like $\Bbb N$: $$\underbrace{0,2,4,6,\dots}_{\text{looks like }\Bbb N},\underbrace{1,3,5,7,\dots}_{\text{looks like }\Bbb N}$$ is an example.

Comment: I understand that a set that doesn't look at all like N (like Q) can nonetheless be arranged to look like N. By looking like N I mean a string with a starting element and each element having a specific successor. What I cannot imagine is how a set can be uncountable and still be able to do that, because if you can arrange them in a string, you can label them e1, e2, .... en, en+1, ... and so on up to $\omega$ (if it is a string there are no jumps)

Comment: @julian: And you can keep going: $\omega+1,\omega+2,\ldots,\omega+\omega=\omega\cdot2,\omega\cdot2+1,\omega\cdot2+2,\ldots,\omega\cdot3,\dots,\omega\cdot4,\dots,\omega\cdot\omega=\omega^2,\dots$. Have you looked at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic)?

Comment: what I mean is that if you have a string you never reach $\omega$, because you do not know what element is the predecessor of $\omega$. I mean, in what I call a string each element has both, a successor and a predecessor.

Comment: (except the first element, of course)

Comment: @julian: Because $\omega$ does not have an immediate predecessor; it’s simply the first ordinal larger than **all** of the natural numbers. However, even what you call a string need not be countable. Let $X$ be the set of all ordered pairs $\langle x,n\rangle$ such that $0\le x\in\Bbb R$, $n\in\Bbb Z$, and $n\ge 0$ if $x=0$. Linearly order $X$ by putting $\langle x,m\rangle\preceq\langle y,n\rangle$ iff $x<y$, or $x=y$ and $m\le n$. (This is called the [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on $X$. Then $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is the first element of $X$, ...

Comment: ... each $\langle x,n\rangle\in X$ has $\langle x,n+1\rangle$ as immediate successor, and each $\langle x,n\rangle\in X$ except $\langle 0,0\rangle$ has $\langle x,n-1\rangle$ as immediate predecessor. But $X$, like $\Bbb R$, is uncountable.

Comment: wow!, thanks for that example!!

Comment: @julian: My pleasure! I hope it helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: how we prove that your mapping is surjective?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slightly worse proof than that given by Brian.

Suppose that the $A$ is the set of countable limit ordinals, then $\bigcup A=\delta=\sup A$ is a countable limit ordinal, therefore $\delta\in A$, but this means that $\delta=\max A$. It is easy to see that $\delta+\omega>\delta$ and it is a countable limit ordinal, in contradiction to the fact that $\delta$ is the largest countable limit ordinal.

Comment: Is "slightly worse" code for "using choice"?

Comment: Andres: Well, not that but it is also an indirect argument by contradiction, whereas Brian's answer is a clear and straightforward bijection. But nonetheless, LOL. :-)

Comment: yes, the argument seems clear. What is not clear is my mind (see my last comment on Scott's answer). There is no way I can imagine a string (meaning that there is one element next to another with nothing in between them) of elements that cannot be labeled by N.

Comment: @julian: Use the fact that everything you can think about is really just a recursive function, or even primitive recursive function, and convince yourself that there is a non-recursive ordinal which is countable. Can you imagine any bijection between that ordinal and $\omega$? No, it's far too complicated. $\omega_1$ is really just "all the ways $\omega$ can be well-ordered". And it turns out that this is also an ordinal, and it cannot be countable for reasons similar to those in my answer above.